# Unrecognized Command: ''LoG 3D'' -- in IMAGEJ Macro Language

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro

I am trying to write a code in macro language of ImageJ in order to automate manuel image analysis work. I have found another website to hande with this problem. Then, I have recently downloaded IMAGEJ v1.52q which is the latest version. Next, I pasted the code into the recorder of Marcos and I run the code. The execution caused 'Unrecognized Command':LoG 3D  Error. I looked at plugin of LoG filters and I only found the one that is released in 2000. I uploaded this one into plugins part of the ImageJ, but I have got the same error. Please let me know if you have any solutions for this problem.

Thank you in advance.

The code I wrote is taken from the website: https://forum.image.sc/t/manual-image-analysis-works-but-not-the-macro-batch/134/15

and it is:

```
macro "Focal adhesion analysis" { 
    dir = getDirectory("Choose a Directory "); 
    list = getFileList(dir); 
    setBatchMode(true); 
    for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) { 
        path = dir+list[i]; 
        open(path);

        run("16-bit");
        run("Subtract Background...", "rolling=50 sliding");
        run("CLAHE ", "blocksize=15 histogram=256 maximum=6");
        title = getTitle;
        run("LoG 3D", "sigmax=4 sigmay=4");
        selectWindow("LoG of "+title);
        setAutoThreshold("Otsu");
        run("Analyze Particles...", "size=1-Infinity circularity=0.05-1.00 clear add");

            path2 = dir+File.nameWithoutExtension; 
            saveAs("JPEG", path2+"-bin.jpeg");
        selectWindow(title);
        run("Revert");
        roiManager("Measure");
                close(); 
                saveAs("results", path2+"-results.tsv"); 
                roiManager("reset");
        } 
}
```

Comment: This may be a silly question, but did you reopen ImageJ after dropping the plugin into the plugins folder?  Can you see the plugin listed in the "Plugins" menu?  If you do, turn on the macro recorder and try running the plugin manually; it could be that the command calling it needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the [CLAHE](https://imagej.net/plugins/clahe/) and [LoG 3D](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/sage/soft/LoG3D/) plugins installed? ImageJ does not come bundled with them.